# How to predict a time series with seasonal pattern in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series

[image: data]
I have data set (download from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15562376/test.csv)), this data set is occupancy level in an office building within 30 days. There is a seasonal pattern daily as you may easily understand.   I tried `diff(t, lag=1440)` but it is still non-stationary. What methods should I use to predict this pattern?

I would like to predict the next few days based on the historical data. I tried different methods in R:

```
a = read.table("test.csv", sep=","); # read data
b = a[,2]  
t = ts(b, frequency = 1440)  # convert to time series 
plot(t)

d = decompose(t)  
plot(d)
acf(d$random,na.action = na.pass)   # non-stationary
Box.test(d$random)
```

Comment: Variations with time of day are called "diurnal" in many fields. It seems simplest to use the term "seasonal" for variations with time of year; there is no obvious reason (to me) for the technical meaning of seasonality to differ much from the ordinary meaning. (This doesn't affect your question.)

Comment: @NickCox  is there any method to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Naturally; @IrishStat has given you one. Another is trend if any plus sinusoids.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I took hourly data for 29 days and used AUTOBOX as the software of choice as far as I know  there is no R implementation for the required procedures to form a robust mixed model taking into account multiple frequencies while isolating unusual values . Perhaps you can proxy this sopution in R. It used a multi-frequency ( 7 and 24 ) approach to forming a basic model which was then improved with Interevention Detection and an appropriate ARIMA model. Here is a graph of the Actual and Forecast . The Actual/Fit/Forecast is a little bit busier. [image] . A plot of the forecasts yields a reasonable view of the next 7 days. [image] with a partial list of the [image]forecasts . The summary statistics for the model are presented here .[image].A number of pulse interventions were found. I present here in chronological order some of them.[image] . This could be used by you as a template so that you can see the art of the possible when you have data by minute , by hour and by day and you wish to incorporate fixed effects and auto-regressive memory while effectively dealing with unusual i.e. non-repetitive data points. If these anomalous data points can be explained/understood then one can incorporate event variables to measure there historical impact and to project them into the future thus not simply discarding their effect.

Comment: How do you set up the parameters?  could you provide more screenshot about the importing and setting?

Comment: Sean, All you ask for is probably off topic for this list. Please contact me at dave@autobox.com and I will try tp help you do all that you need to reproduce what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Using two variables -

1. Hour+Minute/60
2. Day of Week

Here's the prediction based on first 70% of the data, validated on last 30%, using a GBM model.

[image]

It captures the oscilating trend well, but as you can see it fails to capture the daily intensities. If there is any other special significance that can be attached to days (other than weekdays), it can potentially help.